# Why use templates in Kohana?

Tags: templates, kohana, kohana-3

I don't understand the purpose of using templates in Kohana. I see almost no difference in the process of building a view with a template controller vs a regular controller, except that the template controller is tied to a given template and so is less flexible. What are the advantages?

**Building view with regular controller:**

```
Class Controller_Hello extends Controller
{
    public function action_index()
    {   
        $view = View::factory('page');
        $view->page_title = 'My Hello App';
        $view->content = 'hello, world!';
        $view->sidebar = View::factory('parts/sidebar');
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
}
```

**Building view with template controller:**

```
Class Controller_Hello extends Controller_Template
{
    public $template = 'page';

    public function action_index()
    {   
        $this->template->page_title = 'My Hello App';
        $this->template->content = 'hello, world!';
        $this->template->sidebar = View::factory('parts/sidebar');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller_Template is just an example of how you can implement your own templating-system.
It is not ready-to-use solution (at least for my projects usually). Check this one controller (it is also not ready-to-use solution but possibly it will help you understand point of extending different controllers for different purposes): http://pastie.org/2563595

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are other, maybe better solutions for templating systems. But why am I using templates in Kohana?

Think about multiple pages, all based upon one layout/design scheme. So I build a template controller using a certain view, defining layout/design, defining content, header and footer "areas". In the template controller I am loading the CSS files and script files, setting the title and meta values of the website, because every single site is using these CSS/script files with the same meta values and title.

So in every Controller extending the template controller I don't need to load the CSS/script files anew, set the meta values and title etc... But I could change all these values, maybe add a CSS file only for a single site.

Maybe all the mentioned sites have the same footer and/or header: I assign the header/footer view to the template within the template controller, so I don't need to do that in all the controller extending the template controller. Or all actions in one controller have the same header/footer, so I assignt he header and footer few in the before() function of the controller...

For me templates in kohana are a good utility for building small web applications.